# How to make a radar chart using python with data stored in variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, radar-chart

i have 9 values that i calculate and store in variables, now i want to make a radar chart out of these values. After looking at some tutorials i wanted to make a data frame out of the data, like in the following exaple. I only need one colum in the first step.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

thats the example i found on pandas.pydata.org

so i tried this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([avgac], [avgda], [avgen], [avgin], [avgke], [avgli], [avglo], [avgsp], [avgva]),
            columns=['values']
        )
```

If i try to run this i get an error (ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted)
my values which i want to use are in these variables avgac... when i print them it looks like this

```
print("acousticness: ", avgac, ...
```

acousticness:  0.20569285714285715 ....

How could i make a radar chart out of these variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the dataframe in this way:

```
a=1;b=2;c=3;d=4
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Variable":[a,b,c,d],"Name": ["a","b","c","d"]})
```

Replace a,b,c,d.. with the name of your variables.
Then you can use plotly to make the radar chart:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line_polar(df2, r="Variable", theta='Name', line_close=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, that worked. The range (numbers on the x axis, here in your example 0-4) or now set by the values of the variables, so from my understanding this happens in the code with "r="Variable"' i treid to give it a fixed range so i can compare diiferent plots to each other but than it its't working, is it possive to set a fixed range?

Comment: In the Dataframe that I created, the "Variable" column is where the value to plot is, whereas the column "theta" is where the label of that value is. Sorry but I don't understand what you mean with " i tried to give it a fixed range so i can compare different plots to each other". Maybe this link can help you: [here](https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/)

Comment: Thanks again i got it. 
`fig.update_layout(
            polar=dict(
                radialaxis=dict(
                    visible=True,
                    range=[0, 1.2]`
 was what i was searching for, now i can set the range.

Comment: Sorry now I understand what you wanted to do. Great that you figured it out!